# Magento 2 - SessionHandler::gc(): ps_files_cleanup_dir Permission denied (13) in vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler.php on line 138

Tags: magento2, bug

Sometimes I am getting this error lately in Enterprise 2.3.5-p2 after saving CMS pages for example.

> Notice: SessionHandler::gc(): ps_files_cleanup_dir:
> opendir(/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php73) failed: Permission denied
> (13) in
> /home/company/company.de/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler.php
> on line 138

Why is this showing and how can I fix it?

Comment: Any update on this issue as i have same one

Comment: I think this was some issue with redis, you have to set a max connection value in the env.php to a higher value as far as I can remember.